# Regular expression for advanced string

Tags: python, regex, match

Using Python 3.4 I want to match strings which can have the following formats:

```
s1 = "Germany  ; Federal Republic of Germany\tRépublique fédérale d'Allemagne\n"
s2 = "English  ; English language\tanglais\n"
s3 = "February\tfévrier\n"
```

Notice how between the two languages there is a tab-character and if there is more than one word in a language they are divided by `"  ; "` (two blanks, semicolon, one blank).

My goal is to read the first variable of each language. So I want to match

- `s1` to `("Germany", "République fédérale d'Allemagne")`
- `s2` to `("English", "anglais")`
- `s3` to `("February", "février")`

in the case that there is just a pair of vocables or multiple expressions on each side of the `\t`.

Thing is I can't find the right pattern. I have tried multiple expressions (with `search()` and then calling `groups()` on the returned match-object) which don't seem to solve the problem.

Examples with s1:

- `r"([\w ]*)\t([\w ]*)"` finds `(' Federal Republic of Germany', 'République fédérale d')`
- `r"(.*),?\t(.*),?"` finds `('Germany  ; Federal Republic of Germany', "République fédérale
  d'Allemagne")`

Both of these examples don't quite do what I want. And I have no idea what to try next. I am sure there is a way to match `"  ; "` followed any characters until the `\t` but I don't now how.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Try r(\w*)[^\t]*;.*\t(.*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The important thing for you to keep in mind is that the middle section - the optional second bit delimited by ';' - is optional. Regular expressions support optional parts using the `?` operator.

You want to *capture* the first word, ignore the middle part, and capture the final part:

```
(capture) optional? (capture)
```

Because the middle part might be complex, you will need to use parens. But you can use non-capturing parens - `(?: non-captured pattern )` for that.

```
(capture) (?: optional )? (capture)
```

You can probably figure out the rest:

```
#! python3
strings = [
    "Germany  ; Federal Republic of Germany\tRépublique fédérale d'Allemagne\n",
    "English  ; English language\tanglais\n",
    "February\tfévrier\n",
]

import re

for s in strings:
    m = re.match(r"^(\S+)(?:  ; [^\t]+)?\t([^\n]+)\n", s)
    print((m.group(1), m.group(2)))
```

Comment: Thank you. I was missing the bit about non-capturing patterns which is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
res = s.strip().split('\t')
res[0] = res[0].split(';')[0].strip()
```

With regex:

```
import re

pat = re.compile(r'^\s*([^\s\t;]+(?:[^\S\t]+[^\s;]+)*)[^\S\t]*(?:;[^\t]*)?\t\s*(.*\S)')

m = pat.match(s)

[m.group(1), m.group(2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this regex: `([^;\t]+)[;]*[^\t]*([^\n]*)`

The results will have whitespace padding, which you'll probably want to remove.

## Explanation

- `([^;\t]+)`  captures characters that aren't `\t` or `;`
- `[;]*` 0 or more `;`
- `[^\t]*` 0 or more not `\t` characters
- `([^\n]*)` captures 0 or more not `\n` characters

Answer (score 0):

Use this regex:

### `(\w*).*\t(.*)`

The first capture group will contain the single-word name for the language, and the second capture group will contain the message.

[Regex101 Tested](https://regex101.com/r/dU0eI0/2)

Comment: I've updated my answer. My "Regex101 test" was wrong before.

Answer (score 0):

Easy!

```
^(\S+)[^\t]*\t\s*(.+)\s*$
```

### Explanation:

- `^(\S+)`: Get all non-white-space characters in the very beginning of the string.
- `[^\t]*\t`: Ignore everything until the first tab character (`\t`).
- `\s*(.+)\s*$`: Get the rest of the end of the string with trimed left and right white-space.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how it answers the question would significantly improve its long-term value. Please [edit] your answer to add some explanation.